# Get post meta in WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, plugins

I want to show post meta for custom post type in my REST API. I am querying post via slug

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/event?slug=custom-post-slug
```

```
    add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'my_post_type_args', 10, 2 );

    function my_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

        if ( 'event' === $post_type ) {
            $args['show_in_rest'] = true;

            // Optionally customize the rest_base or rest_controller_class
            $args['rest_base']             = 'event';
            $args['post__meta'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, true );
            $args['rest_controller_class'] = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
        }

        return $args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your custom post type to the REST API when registering it with the `register_post_type` function. In the list of arguments, you'll find `show_in_rest`, `rest_base` and `rest_controller_base` ([register_post_type doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)).

Then, you can use the `register_rest_field` function [(documentation)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) to add meta fields to the API.

There's an example for what you need to do:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

    // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'post-meta-fields', array(
           'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
           'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
    //get the id of the post object array
    $post_id = $object['id'];

    //return the post meta
    return get_post_meta( $post_id );
}
```

Simply replace 'post' with your custom post type.

Hope it helps!